# math.random function in lua to position object

Tags: random, lua

```
shape:setY(math.random(0, 450 - 50))
```

math.random function with a minimum and a maximum value is what I understand but what exactly is the meaning of using arithmetic operator in mat.random function, say in above LOC, why is it 450 - 50 and not 400? what is the difference?

similarly,

```
self:setPosition(540, math.random(160) + 40)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no difference. It is equivalent to `shape:setY(math.random(0, 400))`.

The second line of code is equivalent to the following:

```
self:setPosition(540, math.random(1, 160) + 40)
```

It is most certainly intended to be a clearer and/or simpler way of writing

```
self:setPosition(540, math.random(41, 200))
```